# Chef: grafana community recipe error

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, grafana

I'm using the following recipe from chef supermarket: https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/grafana

When I try to execute the following code it crashes:

```
grafana_user 'lechucico' do
  user(
    name: 'lechucico',
    email: 'lechucico@example.com',
    password: 'lechu',
    isAdmin: true,
    organizations: [
      { name: 'Administration', role: 'Admin' },
      { name: 'Marketing', role: 'Admin' }
    ]
  )
  action :create
end
```

This error raises:

```
Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed
==> default: ----------------------------------
==> default: Option user must be a kind of [String]!  You passed {"name"=>"lechucico", "email"=>"lechucico@example.com", "password"=>"lechu", "isAdmin"=>true, "organizations"=>[{"name"=>"Administration", "role"=>"Admin"}, {"name"=>"Marketing", "role"=>"Admin"}]}.
==> default:
==> default: Cookbook Trace:
==> default: ---------------
==> default:   /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/living-grafana/recipes/default.rb:50:in `block in from_file'
==> default:   /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/living-grafana/recipes/default.rb:49:in `from_file'
==> default:
==> default: Relevant File Content:
==> default: ----------------------
==> default: /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/living-grafana/recipes/default.rb:
==> default:
==> default:  43:  #  )
==> default:  44:  #  action :update
==> default:  45:  #end
==> default:  46:
==> default:  47:  grafana_organization 'Marketing'
==> default:  48:
==> default:  49:  grafana_user 'lechucico' do
==> default:  50>>   user(
==> default:  51:      'name' => 'lechucico',
==> default:  52:      'email' => 'lechucico@example.com',
==> default:  53:      'password' => 'lechu',
==> default:  54:      'isAdmin' => true,
==> default:  55:      'organizations' => [
==> default:  56:        { 'name' =>  'Administration', 'role' =>  'Admin' },
==> default:  57:        { 'name' =>  'Marketing', 'role' =>  'Admin' }
==> default:  58:      ]
==> default:  59:    )
==> default:
==> default: Platform:
==> default: ---------
==> default: x86_64-linux
```

Why this isn't working?

Some links with information:

https://github.com/JonathanTron/chef-grafana

https://github.com/JonathanTron/chef-grafana/pull/136

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's due to the fact that despite the pull request has been merged into master, there was no release of the code within master to supermarket.

According to the comments on [this issue](https://github.com/JonathanTron/chef-grafana/issues/174) the ownership of the cookbook is likely to move to the sous-chef group.

If you rely on this latest code, you should download it from git, change its version and push to your chef-server.

You may wish to join Slack #sous-chefs channel on http://community-slack.chef.io/ for more information on the takeover process.

Comment: I'll take a look at sous-chef group. Hope they fix all these errors!